# (Verb + こと) = "The thing I did" vs "Doing"

Tags: grammar

Without context...
選んだこと would either mean

> 1. The thing I chose
> 2. The event of choosing

If the verb is intransitive, it will yield the 2nd meaning. Also the "thing" here is something intangible and abstract.

So I would like to have some tips in distinguishing both.

A : 昨日のパーティは楽しかった

B : 選んだことは面白くなかったのに

Does B imply that "choosing the party was not interesting" or "the event that (I) chose was not interesting"?

Answer (score 2):

It is close to B.

However 選んだこと implies it happened sometime in a while ago, which we can classify as Experience. Just as Have + P.P in English.

So I may consider it as follows :

> 3. The event of having chosen.

p.s. Even if your sentence is correct in grammar, conversation itself is not natural as a whole to my eyes, in other words, not usual colloquial for Japanese natives.